# How to pass method returning file path to file in java?

Tags: java, windows, file-handling, filedialog

I am new to java programming.

`File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\test.txt");`

Here I used 2 /'s to seperate. If I have a method that returns file path as string , how can I pass that in File() for it to work correctly?
The method fileDialogue.getDirectory() that returns path returns it in windows format. So I can't open the file whose path is returned by getDirectory method in FileDialogue.

Comment: In what type is the "path" you get ? class `Path`, `String` ? clarify please

Comment: What are you asking? You have to escape ``\`` (if you use `/` you only need one, regardless of platform) because ``\`` is a special character.

Comment: path is String @azro

Comment: If the string already has the appropriate backslashes in, it should work. Escaping backslashes is required for typing string literals, not of creating `File` objects.

Comment: `return file.getAbsolutePath()` ??